# Multiple instances of react component with different props doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have difficulty with multiple instance of components despite using different key values for them. For example, I make 2 simple pages and pass different props. However, only one of them would log or alert. Shouldn't be one message from each component with their props? What did I miss here?

```
class Temp_page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);   
      console.log("props", props)
      alert("this.props.tag" + this.props.tag);    
  }
  render() {
    return ( <div id={this.props.tag}> {this.props.tag} </div>);
  }
}
```

And the routes:

```
      <Route key="11" path="/temp_1" element = {
        <Temp_page tag={"temp_1"}/>
      }/>     

      <Route key="22" path="/temp_2" element = {
        <Temp_page tag={"temp_2"}/>
      }/>
```

Comment: The url is either going to be `/temp_1`, or `/temp_2` (or neither). It's not going to be both at the same time. So it seems to me to be expected that only one would mount and render. Am i missing something?

Comment: My question is that why both constructors are not being called, even if I click on temp_1 and temp_2 pages. How the component is being rendered before constructor is called?

Comment: It's not being rendered at all. The `<Routes>` component from react-router knows to only render the one that matches.

Comment: When I click on those 2 links, they render as temp_1 and temp_2. So they are rendered but sometime before constructor is called since I see only one of temp_1 and temp_2 in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. The Route component from react-router is designed so that it only renders the route(s) that match. Others do not render at all.

When you do `element = {<Temp_page tag={"temp_1"}/>}`, that does *not* immediatley call the constructor for Temp_page. It just creates an element; in other words, a small object describing what that part of the page should look like. `<Route>` then checks the url. If the url matches, the `<Route>` will return the element you asked it to render, and then react will mount the component, calling its constructor. If instead the url does not match, `<Route>` returns null. The element ends up not being used.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I understand part of the issue, but other part is that one of constructors never gets called (based on the log or alert) despite its render is called and it shows the correct props.

Comment: Try putting the keys on the `<Temp_page>`s instead of the `<Routes>`.

Comment: You are right. That was the issue. Thanks